# How to get path cost in A* shortest path finder of GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, shortest-path, astar

I am computing a shortest path with A* algorithm of [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/):

```
AStarShortestPathFinder pf = new AStarShortestPathFinder(
                                     myGraph, nodeFrom, nodeTo, myAstarfun);
pf.calculate();
Path p = pf.getPath();
```

How could I then retrieve the cost of the computed path `p` ?

With `DijkstraShortestPathFinder`, this can be obtained easily with a `pf.getCost(nodeTo)` but no similar method seems available with A*. I did not find information in [the documentation](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/extension/graph/index.html#shortest-path) to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [`AStarNode`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/extension/graph/src/main/java/org/geotools/graph/traverse/standard/AStarIterator.java#L201)s store the cost so far in their `g` field so something like:

```
cost = ((AStarNode) p.getLast()).getG();
```

should work or if you intend to use the whole path anyway you could do something like:

```
List<Edge> edges = p.getEdges();
double cost = 0;
for (Edge e : edges) {
  cost += myAstarfun.cost((AStarNode)e.getNodeA(),(AStarNode)e.getNodeB());
}
```